# Change styles of parent on hover only if children not focused - Styled components

Tags: css, styled-components

I have a div component:

```
const Parent = styled.div`
   &:not(${Input}:focus):hover {
     border-color: blue;
   }
`;
```

and child which is input

```
const Input = styled.input``;
```

As you can see, I dont want to change `border-color` on `Parent`, if `Input` is focused. However atm the `:hover` doesnt work at all. Looking for help, thanks!

Comment: So in regular css, what you're trying to do is : `.input-container:not(.input:focus):hover { border-color: blue; }`. I don't see how that would work. What you should do is give your `.input-container` a border on `:hover` and cancel out that border on `input:focus`, either using negative box-shadows or by having covering that border with another one.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage `:focus-within` to do that.

```css
div {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
}

div:hover {
  border-color: red;
}

div,
div:focus-within,
div:focus-within:hover {
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you can handle it with only selector css, but you can trick it with javascript.

Your styled-component :

```
const Input = styled.input``

const Parent = styled.div`
  border: 1px solid blue;
  :hover {
    border-color: ${p => p.inputFocus ? "blue" : "yellow"};
  }
`
```

and in your render you can handle a state focus of you input.

render :

```
state = {
    inputFocus: false
}

setFocus = () => this.setState({inputFocus: true})
unsetFocus = () => this.setState({inputFocus: false})

render() {
  const { inputFocus } = this.state
  return (
      <Container inputFocus={inputFocus}>   
        <Input 
          onBlur={this.unsetFocus}
          onFocus={this.setFocus}
        />
      </Container>
  )
}
```